# Drawing the Connection of 2 Arcs with Radius

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, drafting

I am supposed to be re-drawing this image to scale
[image: Original Drawing] However when I Try to connect the arc R11 with arc R26 using the radius R22 I get a negative # in my calculations. i.e. R26-R22=(-4)

[image: Using this formula]

Is there a different way to draw this? I have tried nearly everything and have completed the rest of the drawing except this one point, Am I missing something here?

Comment: Also as a reference my [current drawing] (http://imgur.com/a/x016Z)

Comment: Arc 22 does not connect with arc 26 there is a straight line in between.

Comment: @joojaa had do you know this? what is the length (dimensions) of the line?

Comment: *how did you ascertain that information?

Comment: There is a 44 width dimension that would not be there if there would not be an additional element. Also I can see the end of curvature and they do not coencide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arc 22 does not connect with arc 26 there is a straight horizontal line in between. The hint to this fact is in the width dimension of 44 that would not exist otherwise. There are further hints in the image itself, the small construction line segment shows that its a round of a corner. With a trained eye you can also see in the image the the curvature ends before connect. I have drawn a clarifying image below.

[image]

**Image 1**: Showing construction piece by piece and type (color).